# Detecting first and last item inside a Groovy each{} closure

Tags: html, groovy, closures, markupbuilder

I am using Groovy's handy MarkupBuilder to build an HTML page from various source data.

One thing I am struggling to do nicely is build an HTML table and apply different style classes to the first and last rows. This is probably best illustrated with an example...

```
table() {
  thead() {
    tr(){
      th('class':'l name', 'name')
      th('class':'type', 'type')
      th('description')
    }
  }
  tbody() {
    // Add a row to the table for each item in myList
    myList.each {
      tr('class' : '????????') {
        td('class':'l name', it.name)
        td('class':'type', it.type)
        td(it.description)
      }
    }
  }   
}
```

In the `<tbody>` section, I would like to set the class of the `<tr>` element to be something different depending whether the current item in `myList` is the first or the last item.

Is there a nice Groovy-ified way to do this without resorting to something manual to check item indexes against the list size using something like `eachWithIndex{}`?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You could use

```
if(it == myList.first()) {
   // First element
}

if(it == myList.last()) {
   // Last element
}
```

Comment: Nice tip, didn't know about those methods.

Comment: Just remember, that first() and last() only works on List, not Map or Set (as per http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/)

Comment: I guess it doesn't work on Set is enough since the reason you can't do it on a map is because each iterates over an EntrySet. Upvote.

Comment: and what about eachRow for sql query results? will your solution work in this case?

Comment: @altern eachRow will probably not work, but if you call sql.rows("some query") this returns a List<GroovyRowResult> and here you should be able to call first() and last(), but I have not tried. Check the GDK here: http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html

Comment: Excellent answer, worked for me!!! congratulations for 50 votes!!!

Answer (score 19):

The answer provided by sbglasius may lead to incorrect result like when the list contains redundants elements so an element from inside the list may equals the last one.

I'm not sure if sbglasius could use `is()` instead of `==` but a correct answer could be :

```
myList.eachWithIndex{ elt, i ->
  if(i == 0) {
   // First element
  }

  if(i ==  myList.size()-1) {
   // Last element
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the eachWithIndex :) it's nice

Answer (score 2):

if (it.after.value != null) {
  ......
}

Works for maps